# Rename files in osx from list

Tags: macos, shell

Im using a mac.I have several folders containing png images.

I also have a list of their original file names(the images) and the names that i want to rename them to.

Can any one help me with a script for that ?
(All methods that i have gone through are pattern matching based and they don't mention anything about renaming using a list)

i have the list as csv like this

"Crème Brulee Mica","E2DBCF"

the old name is "Crème Brûlée Mica.png" and the new name should be "E2DBCF.png".Like this i have hundreds of files

Comment: could you tell us some lines of that file?

Comment: ok let me edit the question

Comment: Your title says "linux" but your tag says "osx". Which one is it?

Comment: This (python-based) script looks exactly what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033458/python-rename-files-reading-names-from-csv-file

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e "s/^\"\([^\"]*\)\",\"\([^\"]*\)\"$/mv '\1' '\2'/" | sh
```

... provided you do not have line breaks or single or double quotes in your file names.

Take out the `| sh` to test.

Comment: Spaces are fine, just not quotes (because they would need to be escaped) or newlines (because `sed` does not cope very well with data which is not purely line-oriented, without significant additional effort).

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
#!/bin/bash
renamed=0
failed=0
while IFS=',' read old_name new_name; do
    old_name=`echo ${old_name}.png | sed 's/\"//g'`
    new_name=`echo ${new_name}.png | sed 's/\"//g'`
    if [ -e "$new_name" ]; then
        mv "$new_name" "$old_name"
        #echo "$new_name renamed to $old_name"
        renamed=$[$renamed+1]
    else
        #echo "$new_name not found!"
        failed=$[$failed+1]
    fi
done < "myfile"
echo "success renamed: $renamed"
echo "failed rename: $failed"
```

Via `IFS` I add a delimiter that will save first value in `old_name` and second value in `new_name` variables. 
Then via `sed` command I replaced `"` to none value. then checking file existence if file exists then `mv` command replaces `new_name` to `old_name`. And at the end it will tell you count of `success` and `failed` actions.

**Note:** it works in current directory , except you add directory address in your files names.

Comment: I'm new to this .. can u please explain the working ??

Comment: @MithunMadhav sorry , I updated post. check it. Note: I tried it in Linux platform. hope it works fine for you.

Comment: @MithunMadhav you should change `myfile` to your file name.